# "Unable to get list of updates"

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

im extremely new to ubuntu, and since yesterday i've been unable to update directly from the software center. i open terminal and try `sudo apt-get update`, but i get the error "

```
E: Malformed entry 52 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Malformed entry 52 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read
```

Contents of sources.list:

```
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180725)]/ bionic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
:
```

[Answer by SirCharlo](https://askubuntu.com/a/124024/816190) on [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/q/124017/816190) was my saving grace.

Comment: It would be useful to know what the 52nd entry in /etc/apt/sources.list is.

Comment: how do i find out? ill post the info if i can figure that out...

Comment: Open Terminal and run `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and check line 52

Comment: In a terminal, do `less /etc/apt/sources.list` and count the entries (which ought to begin with `deb`) until the 52nd. Then copy that line and paste it into your question, so we can have a look at it.

Comment: well, it seems i only have 32 entries when i run that. at least that begin with #

Comment: No, entries that begin with "#" are comments and don't count.

Comment: yeah, sorry. im completely lost on this. when i run the command you suggested, the term shows about 50 lines, in which around 30 are comments. so i have only few that dont begin with #

Comment: if it is, i apologize. i have NO knowledge with ubuntu. im 3 days into my first install

Comment: Can you copy the whole file onto `pastebin.com` and give us a link?

Comment: yes sure! one sce

Comment: https://pastebin.com/kG8ZHYVG

Comment: i think im getting somwhere. everything is updating. i didnt have any repositories selected, and other options were unchecked. i used one of the suggested answers. ill select which one helped! thank you guys so much for the help, and i look forward to working with you in the future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several lines appear to have gone missing, and a ":" has appeared where it shouldn't be.

- In a terminal, enter `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` and enter your password.
- Remove the ":" and replace it by:

  ```
  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted 
  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
  ```
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to save the file, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit from nano.
- Do `sudo apt update`.

It should work from here on.

Comment: thank you. right now, everything has started updating and my little i5 is currently "going through the motions". once this is finished, i will return to the terminal and correct the issues that youve found. if i can find them. lol. 
     this wasnt an easy install, but you guys have been a life saver. thank you!

Comment: ALAS! A full restart, and not a single error! Thank you!

Comment: If you think my answer helped you, and you think this is not a duplicate of the questions above, please mark this question as "answered" by clicking the tick mark next to it.